# Office.context.roamingSettings.saveAsync function gives a error when using Dialog API for Office Add-in

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins

i get following error when saving roaming setting value.this Office.initialize method is defined in a dialog box window(myDialog.html) and it is called using 
**Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://myAddinDomain/myDialog.html');**

[image]

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                //console.log("Sending auth complete message through dialog: " + oauthResult.authStatus);
                Office.context.roamingSettings.set("o365auth", 'yyryy');         
                Office.context.roamingSettings.saveAsync(function (asyncResult) {
                    if (asyncResult.status === "success") {
                        var dataValue = result.value; // Get selected data.


                    } else {
                        var err = result.error;

                    }
                });

            });
        }
```

error says "
*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'invoke' of null
    at window.OSF.DDA.OutlookAppOm.u.DDA.OutlookAppOm.invokeHostMethod* "

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently, we only support the Office.context.ui.messageParent API inside the dialog.

Comment: problem is Office.context.roamingSettings.saveAsync() function  does not work inside the dialog window

Comment: You can use Office.context.ui.messageParent API to signal the parent, and call roamingSettings.saveAsync() from the parent that called the dialog.

Comment: @InfoÁsith thanks this helped! we scratched our head straight for 8 hrs after this we have found this.